# how can I use Highcharts.maps['custom/world']?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular9

I want to create a map where I can drilldown the countries.

this is my index.html

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

this is my .ts file

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import MapModule from 'highcharts/modules/map';
import Drilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown';

worldMapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);
```

In series I provide mapData as:

```
series: [{
        mapData: this.worldMapData,
        name: 'My series',
        data: data,
    }]
```

I get the following exception at runtime:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined at Object.a.geojson

Comment: Can you please share the stackblitz for the same?

Comment: So I will check brieffly.